# Clickable XMobar works... but crashes XMobar. What is the modern approach I should follow to have anything I want clickable in XMobar?

Tags: haskell, xmonad, xmobar

(I wrote "clickable XMobar" rather than "clickable workspaces" because eventually I want other plugins to be clickable too.)

##### tl;dr

Defining

```hs
foo = wrap "<action=`touch ~/foo` button=1>" "</action>"
```

or equivalently

```hs
foo = xmobarAction "touch ~/foo" "1"
```

and composing it with `ppCurrent` of xmobar's `PP`

```hs
myXmobarPP :: PP
myXmobarPP = def { ppCurrent = foo . ppCurrent def }
```

results in `touch ~/foo` being indeed executed when clicking on the current workspace's tag, **but it also causes `xmobar` to be killed**.

##### More datails

Gathering various information,

- [`XMonad.Util.ClickableWorkspaces` documentation](https://xmonad.github.io/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Util-ClickableWorkspaces.html),
- [an old question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65230931/clickable-workspaces),
- [Archlinux documentation for XMobar](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xmobar) (I use Arch indeed),
- [XMobar's "Plugin and monitors" doc page](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/branch/master/doc/plugins.org#UnsafeXMonadLog),
- The only paragraph containing `ClickableWorkspaces` at the [XMonad official tutorial](https://xmonad.org/TUTORIAL.html),

I gave a few tries, and these two below are alternative approaches that resulted in a ***partial*** success:

- I changed `XMonadLog` to `UnsafeXMonadLog` in `xmobar.hs`, and passed my `PP` to `clickablePP` (from `XMonad.Util.ClickableWorkspaces`) in `xmonad.hs` (is this the intended modern approach?):

  ```hs
  main = xmonad
       . ewmhFullscreen
       . ewmh
       . withEasySB (statusBarProp (unwords ["xmobar", xmobarhs]) (clickablePP -- instead of return
                                                                   myXmobarPP)) toggleStrutsKey
       $ myConfig
  ```
- Alternatively, I changed `XMonadLog` to `UnsafeXMonadLog` in `xmobar.hs`, and inside my `PP` I've composed `ppHidden` with a function to wrap in the supposedly appropriate action:

  ```hs
  clickable ws = "<action=xdotool key super+"++ws++">"++ws++"</action>"
  myXmobarPP :: PP
  myXmobarPP = def {
    ppHidden          = white . wrap " " "" . clickable,
    -- ...
  ```

In either case, clicking on a workspace *does* move to that workspace... but also kills the `xmobar` process.

I've also tried re-launching xmobar manually from the terminal to see if some error would help me understand

```
xmobar --verbose
```

but the error I see when it gets killed is just `xmobar: waitForProcess: does not exist (No child processes)`

---

Below are the minimal config files (plus non-minimal things you might want to edit to what you're used to, e.g. `modMask`):

- `xmonad.hs`:

  ```hs
  import XMonad
  import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops
  import XMonad.Hooks.StatusBar
  import XMonad.Util.ClickableWorkspaces

  main :: IO ()
  main = xmonad
       . ewmhFullscreen
       . ewmh
       . withEasySB (statusBarProp myxmobar (clickablePP def)) defToggleStrutsKey
       $ myConfig
       where
         myxmobar = "xmobar ~/.config/xmobar/xmobar.hs"

  myConfig = def
      { terminal = "urxvt"
      , modMask = mod4Mask
      }
  ```
- `xmobar.hs`:

  ```hs
  import Xmobar

  main :: IO ()
  main = xmobar defaultConfig {
           overrideRedirect = False
         , position = BottomSize L 100 25
         , commands = [ Run UnsafeXMonadLog ]
         , sepChar  = "%"
         , alignSep = "}{"
         , template = "%UnsafeXMonadLog% }{"
         }
  ```

---

Another attempt:

- I've found that `clickableWrap` has type `Int -> String -> String`, so I tested it in GHCi and verified that `clickableWrap 2 "ciao"` gives back `` "<action=`xdotool set_desktop 2` button=1>ciao</action>" ``,
- I've verified that executing `xdotool set_desktop 2` in a terminal sends be to workspace 3 (apparently `xdotool` has zero-based workspaces),
- and I've edited set `ppHidden` (the `PP` I pass to `statusBarProp`) to `\x -> clickableWrap ((read x :: Int) - 1) x`.

The above still has the same effect that upon click on a hidden workspace brings me to it (good), but kills xmobar (bad).

Comment: Two observations: `Xmobar.App.Compile.recompile` [calls `waitForProcess`](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/commit/3386a05f22ec14ad6383228771966b2f82ae6a58/src/Xmobar/App/Compile.hs#L150); and I can reproduce your issue, but only if I'm using a custom `xmobar.hs` instead of just a `xmobarrc` config ([I've added a little hack to switch back and forth](https://github.com/duplode/xmonad-duplode/blob/3b8e4f8b05d1a0d507e34ea5becc92981e48864e/xmonad.hs#L108)). Now I guess it's time to figure out what one thing can possibly have to do with the other...

Comment: (Tangential note, just in case: the little hack works less well with the xmobar spawning done using `XMonad.Hooks.StatusBar` than with the legacy `XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog`. With the new spawning, changing the path to `xmobar` in `xmonad.hs` and doing Mod-q will result in the previous xmobar not being killed, so you also have to do a `killall xmobar` beforehand if you want to swap the xmobar executable like that.)

Comment: Another observation: If, in `xmonad.hs`, I set the path to xmobar as `~/.config/xmobar/xmobar` instead of `~/.local/bin/xmobar` (thus using the custom xmobar compiled from `xmobar.hs` but without automatic recompilation upon restart), the problem goes away. This strongly suggests the issue has specifically to do with automatic recompilation. A close look at whether anything in [`Xmobar.App.Compile`](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/branch/master/src/Xmobar/App/Compile.hs) can interfere somehow might be necessary.

Comment: @duplode, I've found [another scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77856632/notify-send-from-batteryp-monitor-plugin-causes-waitforprocess-error-in-xmobar) where I get the `waitForProcess` error!

Comment: Interesting... Searching for "no child" in the xmobar bugtracker, I have found [issue #657](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/issues/657), which looks like a very similar problem, but with a different set of plugins.

Comment: @duplode, regarding your second to last comment, if after restarting xmonad (so xmobar with it) I do `kill $(pidof xmobar)`, then everytime I call `xmonad &` the `build` script will be called, even if I haven't changed `xmobar.hs`. This doesn't feel right :/

Comment: No, maybe it is normal.... I guess it's the `cabal build` part that will recompile or not based on whether the `.hs` files in newer than the binary or not?

Comment: Both things are true, I think: on the one hand, if there's a `build` script, XMonad will always call it on startup (see [the section at the end of the install guide](https://xmonad.org/INSTALL.html#dont-recompile-on-every-startup)), and I suppose xmobar does the same thing. On the other hand, cabal won't recompile an unchanged `xmobar.hs` (unless you explicitly ask for that by having `ghc-options: -fforce-recomp` in the .cabal file).

Comment: Yeah, I was just re-reading that page!

Comment: @duplode, I've opened an [issue for xmobar](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/issues/687). I think those repros are pretty minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was a bug in XMobar, which was promptly fixed by the author.

For details, see comments in [my original bug report](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/issues/687) and [the following](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/issues/688).