# Using the BatteryP monitor plugin's -a option causes waitForProcess error in XMobar

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, xmonad, xmobar

Given this `~/.config/xmonad/xmonad.hs`

```hs
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops
import XMonad.Hooks.StatusBar
import XMonad.Hooks.StatusBar.PP

--spawn "xset dpms 0 0 0" >> -- Screensaver

main :: IO ()
main = xmonad
     . ewmhFullscreen
     . ewmh
     . withEasySB (statusBarProp (unwords ["xmobar", xmobarhs]) (pure def)) toggleStrutsKey
     $ myConfig
     where
       toggleStrutsKey XConfig { modMask = m } = (m, xK_b)
       xmobarhs = "~/.config/xmobar/xmobar.hs"

myConfig = def
    { terminal = "urxvt"
    , modMask = mod4Mask
    }
```

and this `~/.config/xmobar/xmobar.hs` (***not* `xmobarrc`!**)

```hs
import Xmobar

main :: IO ()
main = xmobar defaultConfig {
       overrideRedirect = False
       , bgColor  = "#1f222d"
       , fgColor  = "#f8f8f2"
       , position = BottomSize L 100{- reduce this to put system tray -} 25
       , commands = [ Run $ BatteryP ["BAT0"]
                                     ["--template", "<acstatus><left>(<timeleft>)",
                                     "--", "-P",
                                     "-a", "date > ~/battery.out",{-¹-}
                                     "-A", "100"] 50 -- the "100" is to make the notification come up a few seconds after I've unplugged the power on a 100% charged battery
                    ]
       , sepChar  = "%"
       , alignSep = "}{"
       , template = "%battery%"
       }
```

when the battery goes below 100% (well, this is just so I can repro easily without waiting for the battery to go low), the status bar shows this error

```
error: waitForProcess: does not exist (No child processes)
```

However, the file `battery.out` ***is created, and with the expected content!***

---

(¹) My intention is to change that line to

```hs
"-a", "notify-send -u critical 'Battery running out!!'",
```

but apparently `notify-send` is not itself part of the problem.

---

This is ***the same error*** that I'm getting in the (seemingly) unrelated scenario of trying to make workspaces clickable (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77850320/clickable-xmobar-works-but-crashes-xmobar-what-is-the-modern-approach-i-shou) for more details) therefore I'm starting to think that there's something not quite right in my using `xmobar.hs` instead of `xmobarrc`. But I haven't understood yet what.

Comment: I don't have a hypothesis, but my first debugging steps would be to check two things. Does `notify-send -u whatever` do what you expect it to when run in a terminal? Does `notify-send -u whatever` do what you expect it to when spawned from xmonad? If yes, my followup might be to double-check what `xmobar`'s environment looks like, and see if `notify-send` still behaves as expected when spawned from a shell with that environment.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! I've not verified the env of `xmobar` yet. (Since it's in the `IO` monad, I guess I can use XMonad's `spawn` to do something like `env > some.file`.) However, I've verified that the problem is not with `notify-send`. Will check the env this evening.

Comment: The env is not particularly different. And I have `unset` variables that were absent and `export VAR=val` for those which were different. And then run `notify-send`, but it just works.